# How do I export my all of my data from Quickbooks Online?

Tags: export

I want to cancel my Quickbooks account, but want to export my data first.

I went to Reports and exported some of the data to Excel as described here:
[Export Report](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/pages/inproducthelp/core/qb2k12/contentpackage/core/reports_use/task_excel_export.html?family=pro)  But, ideally I would like a file that contains all data that I can import into another app or even back into Quickbooks in the future if necessary.

Is a third party app or another method of extracting all of my data that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following methods:

- Try log-in using Internet Explorer (as Active X is required). From the gear icon go to Export Data. Once Active X is installed, the screens will take you through the export process.

  See: [Download the company file Export to QuickBooks](https://community.intuit.com/questions/820612-download-the-company-file-export-to-quickbooks)
- You may try to install a trial version of [QuickBooks](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/INF21767) that you can install on this computer just to export your data

  > License number: 7482-8847-2621-492
  >
  > Product number: 204–992

If above won't help, contact [QuickBooks Support](https://contactus.intuit.com/) as the export could work only for the US QuickBooks Online at this time.

See also: [How Do I Backup My Data?](https://contactus.intuit.com/en_GB/kb/backing-up-my-data/bdP0KRYKUl)